# How to create a multi color "free flow" gradient with CSS

Tags: css, background-image, gradient, linear-gradients

I want to create a multi colored "free flow" CSS gradient background. It should look something like this:

[image: Gradient I want to achieve]

It seems I need to use a background blend mode. For example screen:

`background-blend-mode: screen;`

The gradient has five colors:

[image: Five colors - A - E]

A: #ecedee
B: #fff0be
C: #fbdce7
D: #e2fae1
E: #d3d5ed

The closest solution I can find is the "Spectrum background" in this [blog post](https://blog.logrocket.com/advanced-effects-with-css-background-blend-modes-4b750198522a/)

```
.spectrum-background {
    background:
        linear-gradient(red, transparent),
        linear-gradient(to top left, lime, transparent),
        linear-gradient(to top right, blue, transparent);
    background-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

But I am not sure how I can add more colors and position them like on the attached image. I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly add more gradients and colors but the tricky part with `blend-mode: screen` is that it becomes white wherever opaque colors overlap.

I found it much easier to work with just gradients, without blending. Here's what I could come up with to match your desired result:

```css
.spectrum-background {
    width: 500px;
    height: 1000px;
    background:
        linear-gradient(150deg, #ecedee, transparent 30%),
        linear-gradient(330deg, rgb(210, 206, 242), transparent 30%),
        linear-gradient(225deg, #fff0be, #fbdce7, #e2fae1, powderblue);
}
```

```html
<div class="spectrum-background"></div>
```

It's not perfectly identical but something you can play with further.

Comment: That's much better and much closer to what I was looking for. Thank you!